# Correct way to start mysqld_safe

Tags: centos, root, mysql

I've been searching around a lot but could not figure out how to start `mysqld` in "safe mode".

This is what I got so far:

```
[root@localhost bin]# service mysqld_safe start
mysqld_safe: unrecognized service
```

I'm running CentOS, this is my mysql version:

```
[root@localhost ~]# mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for redhat-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.1
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting `mysqld` should do the trick:

```
[root@green-penny ~]# service mysqld start
Starting mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
[root@green-penny ~]# ps axu | grep mysql
root      7540  0.8  0.0   5112  1380 pts/0    S    09:29   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --basedir=/usr --user=mysql
mysql     7642  1.5  0.7 135480 15344 pts/0    Sl   09:29   0:00 /usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
root      7660  0.0  0.0   4352   724 pts/0    S+   09:29   0:00 grep mysql
```

(Note that mysqld_*safe* is running.)